# Blue Screen on local dev box -- Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-8, vmware-player

Every time I make a request to create specific objects in the DB, it spins for a bit and blue screens intermittently with the BSOD message:

```
driver_irql_not_less_or_equal (Netio.sys)
```

I think this happens when my dev VM (ubuntu) tries to contact my Elasticsearch machine and it times out:

```
Started POST "/my_object" for 192.168.11.126 at 2015-01-14 11:56:13 -0500
Processing by MyObject#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PmTciB/IcxIf+N6+IWXhb+dISrzXG6lEpzqL4vH5Qjw=", 
"my_object"=>{ ... 
}}
...
   (23.3ms)  COMMIT

SITS AND HANGS HERE

Connection timed out - connect(2) for "[ES IP]" port 9200
Redirected to http://192.168.11.142:3000/
```

The set up is:

- Windows 8 host
- Ubuntu VM (running in bridged mode)

My questions:

1. Why am I blue screening?
2. How can I get around that?
3. Is this an issue with Rails?

Comment: I assume it is something with the VM to Windows causing the BSOD. Are you using a gem that is possibly working it's way out of the VM from the bridging of FS and causing issues?

Comment: I don't believe so. I switched to NAT and it still has the issue.

Comment: share the .dmp files, so that we can see why Windows crashes.